# Getting Error when I deploy ext js app in node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, extjs

I am trying to deploy my ext js app in node server. Steps i have followed.

1.Created a Extjs app using sencha cmd and had used sencha app build to build my app

2. Once after building successfully i have taken my app in build-->production folder to my node server folder.
   [image]

below screenshot contains dbview(client) files[image]

When i start my node server and run my applicaiton using http://localhost:3000 getting following error in my console
 [image]

Please find my server code

```
 var express = require('express')
 var app = express()

  app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname+"\\dbview\\index.html");
   })

      var server = app.listen(3000, function () {

        var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port

   console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port)

   })
```

Help me with the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mount the directory so that express knows to look for static content there, or you could go the long way about it and create a specific route handler for that file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"\\dbview\\index.html");
});

// THIS IS WHAT YOU NEED
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

// OR THE LONG WAY
app.get('/app.json', function(req, res) {
    var options = {
        root: __dirname,
        dotfiles: 'deny',
        headers: {
            'x-timestamp': Date.now(),
            'x-sent': true
        }
    };

    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.sendFile('app.json', options);
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;

    console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

See the Express [Documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html) for further details.